# "Filter" JSON for unique key and get all related values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

What would be the best way to find all the possible related values with a group.

```
var table = [
    {group:"a", stuff:"new"},
    {group:"a", stuff:"old"},
    {group:"b", stuff:"newOld"},
    {group:"b", stuff:"old"},
    {group:"c", stuff:"new"},
    {group:"c", stuff:"old"},
    {group:"c", stuff:"newOld"},
];
```

I want populate a Dropdown containing Unique `group` values. and on selection I want to use all related `stuff` for further processing. and also want to add a group which contains all `stuff`. for example

```
on selection of all -> new, old, newOld
                a -> new, old
                b -> newOld, old
                c -> new, old, newOld
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

short and precise, without the overhead of looking up the entry each time in the whole array:

```
var groups = {all:{}};
table.forEach(function(a){
    if (!groups[a.group]){ groups[a.group] = {}; }
    groups[a.group][a.stuff] = groups["all"][a.stuff] = 1;
});
```

List the stuff in an object, thus you have no duplicate entries (that's why the rather redundant `=1`). But you could easily extend it to count the duplicates:

```
table.forEach(function(a){
    if (!groups[a.group]){ groups[a.group] = {}; }
    var stuff = groups["all"][a.stuff];
    groups["all"][a.stuff] = !stuff ? 1 : ++stuff;
    stuff = groups[a.group][a.stuff];
    groups[a.group][a.stuff] = !stuff ? 1 : ++stuff;
});
```

The result will look like the following:

```
// "groups" holds all group elements and their stuff values
groups = { "all": {"new":2,"old":3,"newOld":2},
           "a" : {"new":1,"old":1},
           "b" : {"newOld":1,"old":1},
           "c" : {"new":1,"old":1,"newOld":1}
         }
```

To retrieve the values of a group, simply say:

```
var groupname = "a"; // whatever group you need
Object.keys(groups[groupname]);
// will give you:
["new","old"]
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv6TY/3)

<sup>Gotta watch out for support of `Object.keys` and `Array.prototype.forEach` of course.</sup>

Comment: this is great solution and thats what I was looking for. I am bit confuse about how I can list all group names. as this is just an example, I have huge dataset on which I want to implement this.

Comment: @anand I extended my answer. Does this help you?

Comment: @christoph Your answer surely helped me. I am using first snippet only.

Answer (score 3):

**SOLUTION:**

Using `grep`, `map` and `unique` (the usage of `unique` can be removed if "All" isn't needed). Here's the code :

```
function getOptions(value) {
    //check if value sent in is an option or "All" options
    var isAll = value === "All" ? true : false;
    var forVal;
    //If its "All" options
    if (isAll) {
        //yes, "All" has been chosen. yay!

        //retreive all the values in "stuff" keys in array
        var internal = $.map(table, function (r) {
            return r["stuff"];
        })
        console.log(internal);
        //get the unique values in internal[]
        forVal = $.unique(internal);

        //or use grep instead if u like to use unique with only DOM elements

    } else {

        //use grep to filter out the other options except the chosen option
        var internal = $.grep(table, function (row) {
            return row["group"] === value;
        });

        //rip out the the values in "stuff" keys in internal[]
        forVal = $.map(internal, function (r) {
            return r["stuff"]
        });
    }
    //return the output variable
    return forVal;
}
```

**SCENARIO** :

We've got a dropdown with these options - `a`, `b`, `c`, `All`.

```
<select id="questions">
    <option>All</option>
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
    <option>c</option>
</select>
```

When an `option` is chosen, you'd like to get the relevant output from `getOption()` and display it as another `select`.

```
$("select").change(function () {
    //remove all #result select boxes - litter of previous option selection
    $("#result").remove();
    //get the options from the getOptions function
    var source = getOptions(this.value);
    //declare a select tag - will be inserted into <body> later
    var $select = $("<select/>", {
        "id": "result"
    });
    //construct an array of <option> tags
    var $options = $.map(source, function (r) {
        return $("<option/>", {
            "html": r
        });
    });
    //append $options to <Select> and then append $select to <body>
    $select.append($options).appendTo("body");
});
```

**DEMO** 
http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/tSR5P/

**EXTRA INFO ABOUT THE METHODS USED IN THIS SOLUTION**

**`map`**

1. Docs : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/
2. What it does : Translate all items in an array or object to new array of items. Kinda like a re-shaper of your `json` object.

**`unique`**

1. Docs : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/
2. What it does : Removes duplicates from an array.

**`grep`**

1. Docs : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/
2. Finds the elements of an array which satisfy a filter function.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is good solution but it will not work out for me as I have huge dataset and I need to create dropdown dynamically.

Comment: @anand you can! Then you could use event delegation to bind the change event and make this work.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want something like this:

```
var groups = {}, container = [], tracker = {};

for (var i = 0, l = table.length; i < l; i++)
{
    var group = table[i].group, stuff = table[i].stuff;

    if (!groups.hasOwnProperty(group)) groups[group] = [];
    groups[group].push(stuff);

    if (tracker.hasOwnProperty(stuff)) continue;
    container.push(stuff);
    tracker[group] = undefined;
}
```

Where groups contains an object of the group data, and container contains all unique values.

Comment: Fair point, but I think there are bigger problems if someone is altering the prototype of arrays...

Comment: for..in is not reliably looping over an array... it does not matter if you alter the prototype or not.

Comment: As far as I'm aware in this instance, on all non-ancient browsers, either loop would give the same results.

Comment: In this example, yes. But it was intended to be a general remark, that it's bad practice to loop over arrays like this, because the order is not guaranteed this way (which often you rely on when iterating over arrays). Also `var a=[];a.foo="bar";for(i in a)...` would also fail.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can work:

```
var table = [
    {group:"a", stuff:"new"},
    {group:"a", stuff:"old"},
    {group:"b", stuff:"newOld"},
    {group:"b", stuff:"old"},
    {group:"c", stuff:"new"},
    {group:"c", stuff:"old"},
    {group:"c", stuff:"newOld"}
];
var groups = {};
var all = [];

for(var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
    var group = table[i];    

    if(typeof groups[group.group] === "undefined") {
        groups[group.group] = [];
    }

    if (all.indexOf(group.stuff) == -1){
        all.push(group.stuff);
    }

    groups[group.group].push(
        group.stuff
    );       
}

all.sort();
```

So the variable `all` hold every possible value and the `groups` contains the values for every group:

```
console.log(groups.a)
> ["new", "old"]
console.log(groups.b)
> ["newOld", "old"]
console.log(groups.c)
> ["new", "old", "newOld"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Look sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/)

```
var table = [
    {group:"a", stuff:"new"},
    {group:"a", stuff:"old"},
    {group:"b", stuff:"newOld"},
    {group:"b", stuff:"old"},
    {group:"c", stuff:"new"},
    {group:"c", stuff:"old"},
    {group:"c", stuff:"newOld"},
];

    var filter = function(selected) {    
        var newArr = [];
        $.each(table, function(idx, item){
            if((selected == null || selected == item.group) && $.inArray(item.stuff, newArr) == -1) {
                newArr.push(item.stuff);
            }
        });    
        return newArr;
    };

// using
    console.log(filter('a'));

// for selecting 'all'
    console.log(filter(null));
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for bumping this question after such a long time, but I couldn't find the way I'd do this.

I would take an easier (but probably less optimized) ES6 approach:

We start with the table

```
const table = [
    { group: "a", stuff: "new" },
    { group: "a", stuff: "old" },
    { group: "b", stuff: "newOld" },
    { group: "b", stuff: "old" },
    { group: "c", stuff: "new" },
    { group: "c", stuff: "old" },
    { group: "c", stuff: "newOld" }
];
```

Then we want all the unique group values as an array so we can easily loop over it in an select element.

```
// Get all unique group entries in the table and map them to the value of group
const uniqueGroups = table.filter((entry, index, self) => {
    // findIndex will return the index of the first found result
    return self.findIndex(a => a.group === entry.group) === index;
).map(entry => entry.group);
```

For sake of argument, imagine someone clicked on a group.

```
// Image someone clicked on the group "c"
const chosenGroup = uniqueGroups[2]; // This would be the event handler value of the chosen option
```

Then we filter out all entries in the table corresponding to that group value and map the enties to the stuff values.

```
// Get all stuff related to chosen group
const stuff = table.filter(entry => entry.group === chosenGroup).map(entry => entry.stuff);
```

I think this is way easier and totally fine for small amounts of data.