# JavaScript looping through multimensional JSON arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I've been unable to locate the correct solution to my problem here. I'd like to loop through the nested Products arrays to display each Product name. Is it possible with what I've written, or do I need to re-write it in a way that allows me to query what I need easier?

```
            [
               {
                  "category":"A",
                  "products":[
                   {
                     "id":1,
                     "name":"Product 1",
                     "description":"Description of my product 1."
                   },
                   {
                     "id":2,
                     "name":"Product 2",
                     "description":"Description of my product 2."
                   },
                   {
                     "id":3,
                     "name":"Product 3",
                     "description":"Description of my product 3."
                   }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "category":"B",
                  "products":[
                   {
                     "id":4,
                     "name":"Product 4",
                     "description":"Description of my product 4 in cat B."
                   },
                   {
                     "id":5,
                     "name":"Product 5",
                     "description":"Description of my product 5 in cat B."
                   },
                   {
                     "id":6,
                     "name":"Product 6",
                     "description":"Description of my product 6 in cat B."
                   }
                  ]
               }
            ]
```

Comment: I think what you're looking for has been answered here :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298443/filter-json-for-unique-key-and-get-all-related-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that this whole structure is in a variable called `data`:

```
data.forEach(function(category) {
    if (category.hasOwnProperty('product')) {
        category.products.forEach(function(product) {
            console.log(product.name);
        });
    }
});
```

The outer `forEach` loops through all of the category objects. The inner forEach loops goes through all of the products objects in each category.

Answer (score 1):

In general looping through an array `things = [...]` is done like this:

```
for( var i=0; i<thing.length; i++ ) {
    // do stuff with thing[i]
}
```

Looping through an object `things = {...}` is done like this:

```
for( key in things ) {
    if( things.hasOwnProperty(key) ) {
        // do stuff with things[key] or key.
    }
}
```

You can nest them all you like.

In your case, if we name your original data structure `items`, then
(see http://jsfiddle.net/7yc5arLe/):

```
for( item=0; item<items.length; item++ ) {
    console.log('category is '+items[item].category);
    for( product=0; product<items[item].products.length; product++ ) {
        p = items[item].products[product];
        for( key in p ) {
            console.log('  product '+key+' is '+items[item].products[product][key]);
        }
    }
}
```

will output

```
category is A
  product id is 1
  product name is Product 1
  product description is Description of my product 1.
  product id is 2
  product name is Product 2
  product description is Description of my product 2.
  product id is 3
  product name is Product 3
  product description is Description of my product 3.
category is B
  product id is 4
  product name is Product 4
  product description is Description of my product 4 in cat B.
  product id is 5
  product name is Product 5
  product description is Description of my product 5 in cat B.
  product id is 6
  product name is Product 6
  product description is Description of my product 6 in cat B.
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible.

- To loop over an array [] :

  ```
  for (initialization; condition; update) {
      ...
  }
  ```
- To loop over an object {} :

  ```
  for (variable in object) {
      if (object.hasOwnProperty(variable)) {
          ...
      }
  }
  ```